# ASP.NET Entity Framework DateTime always set to 01-01-00001

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datetime, datetimepicker, datetime-format

as per the title, I have a problem with the datepicker in asp.net: every time i try and set a date, it always shows as '01-01-0001' on the controller.
This is my View (it's an Edit, so I have changed the format in the input, otherwise the Date taken from the database woudln't show up) :

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ExamDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @*RIVEDERE INPUT DATA IN EDIT EXAM*@
                @*@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ExamDate, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new {@type = "date", @value = Model.ExamDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")})*@
                <input id="ExamDate" type="date" value="@Model.ExamDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" />
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ExamDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is the Controller:

```
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Exams exams = db.Exams.Find(id);
            if (exams == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            TempData["IDAnimal"] = exams.IDAnimal;
            
            return View(exams);
        }

        // POST: Exams/Edit/5
        // Per la protezione da attacchi di overposting, abilitare le proprietà a cui eseguire il binding. 
        // Per altri dettagli, vedere https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ExamID,ExamDate,Exam,ExamNotes")] Exams exams, int id)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                exams.ExamID= id;   
                exams.IDAnimal = Convert.ToInt32(TempData["IDAnimal"]);
                db.Entry(exams).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Details", "Animals", new { id = exams.IDAnimal});
            }
            
            return View(exams);
        }
```

And the Model is a simple DateTime property

Edit: here's the Model:

```
 public partial class Exams
{
    [Key]
    public int ExamID { get; set; }

    public int IDAnimal { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime ExamDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string Exam { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ExamNotes { get; set; }

    public virtual Animals Animals { get; set; }
}
```

I don't really have a clue as to why it's behaving this way, the only thing I can think of is of some issue with the date format, but I don't really know how else I'm supposed to show it on the page if not in that particular format I used on the View

Comment: Hows your model looks, could you please share your model details?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron just added the code

Comment: `0001-01-01` is the default `DateTime` value which means you're trying to display a value that was never set.